# How do I fix this "Error in From clause"?

Tags: sql, mysql

for this specific problem I had to enter the query:

```
SELECT ProductName, Quantity 
FROM Products 
JOIN OrderDetails 
  on OrderDetails.Productid= Products.Productid 
WHERE Quantity <5
```

On the website:
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_all

The question that I got this query from from was "Can you modify the SQL so that the results also display the price of each item? Copy all the records shown as results and paste them into your lab document."

The first thing I Tried was reveiwing the way things for spelled and I didnt find any problems. Then I tried to look at the table and chosing a product, getting the Product ID, the Product name the supplier ID, the catagory ID and the quantity of the products orders. That did not work either.

Comment: What error and what didn't work?

Comment: The `FROM` seems fine. If you're trying to add new columns it's `SELECT` you need to worry about

Comment: Weird. I guess that dialect wants INNER
JOIN instead of just JOIN.

Comment: It's good programming practice to _qualify_ all columns, at least when several tables are involved. Like `tablename.Quantity` instead of just `Quantity`.

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance.

Comment: Improve readability and reduce space by aliasing your table names.... `select p.productname, od.quantity from products p join orderdetails od on p.productid = od.productid...`

Comment: Skip w3_ools... Too many errors at that place.

Comment: Did you try putting a space with the equal?
 on OrderDetails.Productid= Products.Productid  into
 on OrderDetails.Productid = Products.Productid  into ?

Answer (score 2):

According to the MySQL manual 'In MySQL, JOIN, CROSS JOIN, and INNER JOIN are syntactic equivalents (they can replace each other)'.  However, the SQL editor on this particular website seems to require an explicit `INNER JOIN` (not just `JOIN`)

Answer (score 0):

You are missing INNER on the join

SELECT ProductName, Quantity

FROM Products

**INNER** JOIN OrderDetails

on OrderDetails.Productid= Products.Productid

WHERE Quantity <5